# Multi-lined condition of a piecewise function

Tags: multline

How can I add a second line to the condition in my piecewise function? I'm using the `multlined` environment, but it's producing quite an ugly result:

[image]

Ideally, I would want the two conditions right on top of each other, and without any indentation. The code is pretty ugly, but it's pretty much just:

```
\begin{cases}
..... & \begin{multlined}
    .....\\
    .....
\end{multlined}\\
..... & \begin{multlined}
    .....\\
    .....
\end{multlined}
\end{cases}
```

Here's the full code:

```
\begin{equation}
    \forall m \geq a_{a}, s_{a}(m) = \begin{cases}
        \mathlarger{\sum\limits_{e=0}^{\left\lfloor\tfrac{a}{8}\right\rfloor}{\tfrac{\left\lfloor\tfrac{m}{2}\right\rfloor^{2}-\left\lfloor\tfrac{m}{2}\right\rfloor}{2} \choose e}{m-1 \choose \tfrac{2\left\lfloor\tfrac{a}{8}\right\rfloor-8e}{4}}} &\begin{multlined}
            a\equiv 0 \Mod{4},\\
            m\equiv 1 \Mod{2}
        \end{multlined}\\
        \mathlarger{\sum\limits_{e=0}^{\left\lfloor\tfrac{a}{8}\right\rfloor}{\tfrac{\left\lfloor\tfrac{m}{2}\right\rfloor^{2}-\left\lfloor\tfrac{m}{2}\right\rfloor}{2} \choose e}{\tfrac{m}{2} \choose \tfrac{2\left\lfloor\tfrac{a}{8}\right\rfloor-8e}{4}}} &\begin{multlined}
            a\equiv 0 \Mod{4},\\
            m\equiv 0 \Mod{2}
        \end{multlined}\\
        \mathlarger{\sum\limits_{e=0}^{\left\lfloor\tfrac{a}{8}\right\rfloor}{\tfrac{\left\lfloor\tfrac{m}{2}\right\rfloor^{2}-\left\lfloor\tfrac{m}{2}\right\rfloor}{2} \choose e}{m-1 \choose \tfrac{2\left\lfloor\tfrac{a}{8}\right\rfloor-8e}{4}}} &\begin{multlined}
            a\equiv 1 \Mod{4},\\
            m\equiv 1 \Mod{2}
        \end{multlined}\\
        0 &\begin{multlined}
            a\equiv 1 \Mod{4},\\
            m\equiv 0 \Mod{2}
        \end{multlined}\\
        0 & a > 1 \Mod{4}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `\begin{multlined}...\end{multlined}` environment, I just used the `\begin{split}...\end{split}` environment. That produced this result:

[image]

In case anyone wants to see, here's the full code:

```
\begin{equation}
    \forall m \geq a_{a}, s_{a}(m) = \begin{cases}
        \mathlarger{\sum\limits_{e=0}^{\left\lfloor\tfrac{a}{8}\right\rfloor}{\tfrac{\left\lfloor\tfrac{m}{2}\right\rfloor^{2}-\left\lfloor\tfrac{m}{2}\right\rfloor}{2} \choose e}{m-1 \choose \tfrac{2\left\lfloor\tfrac{a}{8}\right\rfloor-8e}{4}}} &\begin{split}
            a\equiv 0 \Mod{4},\\
            m\equiv 1 \Mod{2}
        \end{split}\\[2em]
        \mathlarger{\sum\limits_{e=0}^{\left\lfloor\tfrac{a}{8}\right\rfloor}{\tfrac{\left\lfloor\tfrac{m}{2}\right\rfloor^{2}-\left\lfloor\tfrac{m}{2}\right\rfloor}{2} \choose e}{\tfrac{m}{2} \choose \tfrac{2\left\lfloor\tfrac{a}{8}\right\rfloor-8e}{4}}} &\begin{split}
            a\equiv 0 \Mod{4},\\
            m\equiv 0 \Mod{2}
        \end{split}\\[2em]
        \mathlarger{\sum\limits_{e=0}^{\left\lfloor\tfrac{a}{8}\right\rfloor}{\tfrac{\left\lfloor\tfrac{m}{2}\right\rfloor^{2}-\left\lfloor\tfrac{m}{2}\right\rfloor}{2} \choose e}{m-1 \choose \tfrac{2\left\lfloor\tfrac{a}{8}\right\rfloor-8e}{4}}} &\begin{split}
            a\equiv 1 \Mod{4},\\
            m\equiv 1 \Mod{2}
        \end{split}\\[2em]
        0 &\begin{split}
            a\equiv 1 \Mod{4},\\
            m\equiv 0 \Mod{2}
        \end{split}\\[1.5em]
        0 & a > 1 \Mod{4}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Consider adding an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) which produces the output you showed.